Basic stems that end in "w"?
I am reading "Essential Japanese Grammar" (from Dover) by Everett F. Bleiler. The section about the consonant conjugation lists some verb examples in their present form with corresponding basic stems next to them:

PRESENT FORM            BASIC STEM
shimau      to finish   shima-*
kau         to buy      ka-*
iu          to say      i-*
omou        to think    omo-*

* Strictly speaking these stems end in a -w-; for convenient exposition we can ignore this -w-.

I just don't get it. Where is this -w- supposed to be? It has hyphens on both sides, which means it's not a suffix or prefix, it is implied to stand in between other letters. The only place I can imagine this -w- appear is right before the -u, correct me if I am wrong.
What's your take on this? What do they mean? By the way, there is a handful of other verbs in that table right after the ones I listed. They are not marked with the star and all end in -ru. (In case you wondered what was meant by "convenient exposition.")
Thank you.

I assume they are referring to the fact that 買う becomes 買わない to avoid doubling the 'a' sound. Similarly, one says 言わない to avoid having the 'i' and 'a' sounds clash.

@Saegusa, for some reason the contents of my message do not display correctly. There's some interference, I don't know what causes it (must be some characters). I apologize. And thank you for you comment.

The term 'stem' when it comes to Japanese usually refers to the so-called 連用形 'continuative form' of a verb. In Modern Japanese, there are two types of verbs (outside of exceptions), 一段 'ichidan' and 五段 'godan'. The first ones are sometimes called 'ru-verbs' and the second ones 'u-verbs' since the first type always end in る. In the case of 一段 verbs, the stem is found by dropping る, for instance 閉める becomes 閉め. In the case of 五段 verb, change the last 'u' hiragana into its corresponding 'i' hiragana, for instance 買う becomes 買い.
This is usually what is called the 'stem' of the verb. Your book seems to use the word 'stem' more generally to refer to any kind of verb base, which is somewhat unusual. In this case, it is referring to the 未然形, the verb base associated with the negative form in Japanese (among other things). For 一段 verbs, nothing changes but for 五段 verbs, you need to change the last 'u' hiragana into its corresponding 'a' hiragana. There is one exception: if the final hiragana is う, we use わ instead to avoid having clashing vowel sounds, for instance 買う becomes 買わ(+ない in the negative). This is what your textbook is referring to, and it's true for the other verbs you list: 言う becomes 言わない, 思う becomes 思わない, etc. Notice how the 'w' sounds is in between the kanji and the okurigana, I assume this is why they wrote it -w-.
If you would like to know more about the 連用形, the stem of Japanese verbs, please check this question.

Thank you. I wonder why they didn't just simply write "-wa" instead of "-w-" then. Could it be that in some cases "wo" would follow instead of "wa"?

I am not sure myself. No, 'wa' is the only thing that follows (in the 未然形 I mean).

@bp2017, they say "w" because of historical sound changes in Japanese.  See also this other post of mine about the "h" kana.

In linguistics (and presumably used so in that book), stem is "part" of given word without inflectional affixes, but it does not need to be equal to any form (including lemma) of that word, does not need to follow phonotactic rules for words in given language, and does not even need to be strict subset of any form of that word. Stems of consonant-stem verbs (五段), as name implies, end with consonants. E.g. karu has stem kar-, and kau (Old Japanese kapu) has stem kaw- (Old Japanese kap-).

About stem not necessarily being strict subset of any form of given word: There are sometimes cases when different processes affect different forms of given word, resulting in them diverging. E.g. stem of Classical Latin noun corpus (genitive corporis) can be argued to be corpos-. Nominative is formed by suffix -s (*corpos-s, with simplification of word-final double ss to s), and /o/ in word-final os is raised to /u/, resulting in corpus. In genitive and other cases, which are formed by suffixes beginning with vowels, stem-final s is rhotacized to r (e.g. corporis).

@Arfrever, it's weird because there is no "w" kana in Japanese. I suppose it's because more than one of the following can follow the basic stem with "w" at the end: -a, -e, -i, -o (making it -wa-, -we-, -wi-, or -wo- as part of inflection, the beginning part of inflection to be precise). But that's just my uneducated guess.

There were /we/, /wi/, /wo/ sounds in Japanese, but in Old Japanese (8th century) maybe there were no verbs whose stems ended in /w/. At some time (second part of 10th century according to Frellesvig), intervocalic and usually morpheme-medial /p/ changed to /w/, and automatically disappeared before /u/ (e.g. 川: /kapa/ → /kawa/, 返る: /kaperu/ → /kaweru/, 買ふ: /kapu/ → /kau/). Hiragana and katakana were created somewhen during Middle Japanese, and retroactively using them for Old Japanese is not very good idea, since Old Japanese had more vowels or semivowel-vowel sequences.

Even after aforementioned /p/ → /w/ change, spelling with p kana (は・ハ, ひ・ヒ, ふ・フ, へ・ヘ, ほ・ホ) remained for about 1000 years until reform of orthography in 1946. See Historical kana orthography. ゐ・ヰ were kana characters for original /wi/, and ゑ・ヱ were kana characters for original /we/. In actual pronunciation, /wi/ and /we/ (both original and from intervocalic /pi/, /pe/) also disappeared, more exactly changed to /i/ and /je/ respectively, somewhen in 11th - 13th centuries.

E.g. modern verb 居る /iru/ was spelt in kana as ゐる until 1946, and was pronounced as /wiru/ before 1300 (according to Frellesvig).

@Arfrever Nitpicking a little: since corpus is neuter, there would be no nominative -s added – that’s for animate nouns only. Historically, the oblique stem was *corpes-, with the -e- changing to -o- in Latin due to the preceding labial (in other neuter s-stems without a labial, it remained -e-, as in genus/generis), but internally in Latin, corpos- does make more sense.

@bp2017 It’s very useful to have a basic grasp of the historical sound changes in Japanese, as they can help make sense of a lot of things that otherwise look odd or irregular. As Arfrever’s says, these verbs have inflectional stems that end in -w-, so it’s really kaw-, etc. The original /p/ turned into /w/ between vowels, so /kap-V/ → /kaw-V/ (then later disappeared before /e i o u/); but before another consonant, it remained /p/ and the two assimilated, so past tense /kap-ta/ → /katta/. This is why these verbs (which otherwise look like vowel stems now) have -tt- in the past tense.

@bp2017 And also remember that the inflectional stems of verbs are completely unrelated to kana. Verbs had abstract inflectional stems long before Japanese was written down. Kana reflect how Middle and Modern Japanese phonotactics work at the surface level, but stems are not surface-level entities. A verb like 待つ matsu ‘wait’ has the stem mat-, which never appears as a standalone form – it only shows up in the 未然形 and 仮定形/命令形. I would recommend reading the Wikipedia page on Japanese verb categories to understand the system.

@JanusBahsJacquet You are right about suffix of nominative case of corpus. Regarding Japanese past tense, which was previously perfective-progressive aspect (when there was simple past tense formed by -ki / -si / -siki suffix), development using /katta/ example probably was: 連用形 /kap-i/ + /-te/ + /aru/ → /kapitaru/ → /kawitaru/ → /kautaru/ (western) ~ /kattaru/ (eastern) → /kɔːtaru/ (western) ~ /kattaru/ (eastern) → /kɔːta/ (western) ~ /katta/ (eastern) → /koːta/ (western) ~ /katta/ (eastern).

Correction to my last comment. I forgot about U-onbin process, and there is evidence that onbin started to occur before change of intervocalic /p/ to /w/. Forms without onbin and with onbin were co-existing for some centuries (with forms without onbin being used more likely in poetry and formal or careful language).

Development for /katta/ example would have been: 連用形 /kap-i/ + /-te/ + /aru/ → /kapitaru/. Next, (1) in no-onbin route: /kapitaru/ → /kawitaru/ → /kaitaru/ → extinction at some point in time; (2) in U-onbin route (ultimately preferred in western dialects): /kapitaru/ → /kautaru/ → /kɔːtaru/ → /kɔːta/ → /koːta/; (3) in Q-onbin route (ultimately preferred in eastern dialects): /kapitaru/ → /kattaru/ → /katta/.
